# Uncaught Error: Class 'Client' not found in chat-api

Tags: php, api, class, composer-php, whatsapp

Im not good usig php, i just installed composer and just created this composer.json in my new project directory:

```
{
    "require": {
        "chatapi/whatsapp": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

then I created a file named "whatsapp-sender.php" with the following:

```
<?php

require "vendor/autoload.php";

$client = Client::getInstance([
   'url' => '<ULR>',
   'token' => '<TOKEN>'
]);

$client->sendMessage([
   'phone' => '<PHONE_NUMBER>',
   'body' => 'Hi there!'
]);

?>
```

but when i try to run it to send a message this error appeared:

> F:\BotGenes\PHP\Chat-api>php whatsapp-sender.php PHP Fatal error:
> Uncaught Error: Class 'Client' not found in
> F:\BotGenes\PHP\Chat-api\whatsapp-sender.php:5 Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 {main}   thrown in F:\BotGenes\PHP\Chat-api\whatsapp-sender.php on line 5
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Client' not found in
> F:\BotGenes\PHP\Chat-api\whatsapp-sender.php:5 Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 {main}   thrown in F:\BotGenes\PHP\Chat-api\whatsapp-sender.php on line 5

Can somebody help me please?

Comment: Namespace, and USE statement.  `chatapi/whatsapp/Client::getInstance(...)`  or whatever the namespace is, I'm just guessing here.  My IDE (Eclipse PDT) automatically does Namespaces so I don't worry about that.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix something like this?

`$client = vendor\chatapi\whatsapp\src\Client::getInstance([
   'url' => 'https://eu39.chat-api.com/instance29044/',
   'token' => '0h751ixjntw1u9qi'
]);`

Comment: Like `chatapi\WhatsApp\Client::getInstance(/*...*/)`.